# Set non-root user's environment in Dockerfile such that its modified version is available at build time

Tags: docker

I've been unsuccessfully trying to set the `PATH` of a non-root user of a Docker image such that its modified version would be available to me at build time. Below is a minimal `Dockerfile` that illustrates what I'd like to achieve:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN adduser nonroot
RUN su - nonroot -c 'mkdir ~/foo'
RUN su - nonroot -c 'echo "echo Hello, World" > ~/foo/hello'
RUN su - nonroot -c 'chmod +x ~/foo/hello'
RUN su - nonroot -c 'echo '\''export PATH="$PATH:~/foo"'\'' >> ~/.bashrc'
USER nonroot 
RUN hello #Should print out 'Hello, World'
```

It doesn't work as I'd expect, though - I get a failure with a "/bin/sh: 1: hello: not found" message.

Is there anyway to achieve this in Docker? If not, how do people setup in their `Dockerfile` a new user that'd require such changes?

Answer (score 0):

When you run `hello` from the `Dockerfile`, note that the build gives this error message :

```
The command '/bin/sh -c hello' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

Docker executes the command `hello` in a non-interactive shell (with `/bin/sh -c <command>`) to create a layer, and in a non-interactive session, files like `~/.profile`, `~/.bashrc`, etc., are not sourced.

In your `Dockerfile`, I think you would rather use directly `~/foo/hello`. But you can keep the `.bashrc` for interactive sessions of your container.

For information, you could also make a symbolic link in a directory already existing in `$PATH`, like this (put in your `Dockerfile`) :

```
RUN ln -s /home/nonroot/foo/hello /usr/local/bin/hello
RUN chown nonroot:nonroot /usr/local/bin/hello
```

But I do not recommend it (using `~/foo/hello` is a better option to me).

Answer (score 0):

Just install software in the "normal" locations like `/usr/bin`.  Since the Dockerfile fully documents what you did and containers usually do "just one thing" there's not really any harm in doing this.

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
COPY hello /usr/bin
RUN adduser nonroot
USER nonroot
CMD ["hello"]
```

If you needed to set some global environment variables, use the Dockerfile ENV directive.

Remember that if you use a CMD like this it doesn't go through a shell at all; if you do have a shell, it probably isn't a login shell; and the lighter-weight base images won't have GNU bash and its various non-portable extensions.  At least in my mostly server-oriented Docker work I've never needed to add shell dot files to an image.